# pandas df.rename on both indices and columns not always working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have a list of dataframes and I iterate over them, renaming all the columns/indices using one pandas [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method call.

```
df.rename(
    {
        'vol': 'Volume Sales',
        'val': 'Value Sales',
    },
    index={
        't1': info['literal_periods'][0],
        't2': info['literal_periods'][1],
        'acv': '% ACV Distribution',
        'aic': 'Average Items Carried',
        'tdp': 'Total Distribution Points',
        'vol': 'Volume Sales',
        'psl': 'Promo Sales',
        'Share of AIC': '{} share of {} AIC'.format(
            info['name'], info['p1']),
        'Share of TDP': '{} share of {} TDP'.format(
            info['name'], info['p1']),
        'Target Product': info['name'],
        'target product': info['name'],
    },
    columns={
        't1':
        info['literal_periods'][0],
        't2':
        info['literal_periods'][1],
        'promo change':
        '% change from ya',
        'non promo change':
        '% change from ya',
        'sales change':
        '% change from ya',
        'val':
        'Value Sales (£)',
        'vol':
        'Volume Sales (L)',
        'volsu':
        'Volume Sales (units)',
        'litres per unit':
        'litres/unit',
        't2 Promo Sales':
        '{} Promo Sales'.format(info['literal_periods'][1]),
        't2 Non-Promo Sales':
        '{} Non Promo Sales'.format(info['literal_periods'][1]),
        't2 Total Sales':
        '{} Total Sales'.format(info['literal_periods'][1])
    },
    inplace=True)
```

It seems to work perfectly for some tables, partially for others and then not at all for some. Why?
For example the 'aic' index is not being renamed properly in a df with 'aic' in it even though the column 'vol' is correctly being mapped to 'Volume Sales' in the same df.

Comment: Can you provide a (small) sample dataframe that reproduces the problem?  And can you reduce your `.rename()` statement to be only as large as necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: do `df.columns` and check that there isn't extra trailing or leading whitespace on the column names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Pandas documentation on rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) where parameters `mapper, index, columns` are explained, it's written:

Use **either** *mapper and axis* to specify the axis to target with mapper, or *index and columns*

In what you give as example,

```
{
    'vol': 'Volume Sales',
    'val': 'Value Sales',
}
```

which is understood by the function as `mapper =` and then you give `index` and `columns`. Without being able to reproduce, it's possible that the function `rename` has some "troubles" to understand the parameters you give (I guess looking at the code behind would give the reason why)

This also explains why the column `'vol'` is rename `'Volume Sales'` and not `'Volume Sales (L)'` as define in `column=`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the first few lines:

```
df.rename(
    {
        'vol': 'Volume Sales',
        'val': 'Value Sales',
    },
```

I'm not sure why, but once I removed the first two mappings it started working. My guess is that the way df.rename works is if you pass a general mapping and it finds a term within your df matching one of the keys, then it will only look for those and not care for your specific index and columns mappings.